# Livewire checkbox preselected not working

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have collection of permission_types which i can access in my view. I am looping the permission_types to show each one in check box. all the checkboxes are binded to permission_resource, which is defined as a public property array. **I want all the checkboxes to be preselected** for which i used **checked** attribute but it won't work, as soon as i remove the wire:model attribute from input all the checkboxes are preselected. which narrows down the problem to wire:model binding.

**What i am trying to achieve:**

**All i want to do is preselect the checkboxes binded to public property $permission_resource**. Can anyone please help me out. I really cannot figure out what am i doing wrong here. Appreciate any effort to solve this problem in advance.

**Relevent Component Code:**

```
public $permission_types;
public $permission_resource = [];

public function render()
{
    $this->permission_types = PermissionType::all();
            
    // dd($this->permission_types->toArray());
            
    return view('livewire.permissions.create-permission-component')
            ->extends('layouts.app')
            ->section('content');
}
```

**Relevant View Code:**

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($this->permission_types as $permissionType)
        <div class="col-md-3">
             <input wire:model="permission_resource" type="checkbox" class="filled-in chk-col-green form-control" id="{{$permissionType['name']}}" value="{{ $permissionType['name'] }}" checked />
            <label for="{{ $permissionType['name'] }}" class="p-r-30">{{ ucfirst($permissionType['name']) }} Resource</label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**Permission Types Dump**

[image]

**What i have tried so far:**

so far i have tried following but none of it worked for me.

1: defining **public $permission_resource;** instead of **public $permission_resource = [];**

2: wire:model="permission_resource.{{$permissionType["id"]}}"

3: wire:model="permission_resource.{{$permissionType["name"]}}"

4: wire:model.defer="permission_resource.{{$permissionType["id"]}}"

5: wire:model.defer="permission_resource.{{$permissionType["name"]}}"

6: name="permission_resource.{{$permissionType["id"]}}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding all the inputs to the same (array) variable, what you want to do is bind each to an element in that array, not to the array itself.

So you would need to prepopulate that array, and then bind each input using `$loop->index`.

Not sure if you have a good reason for populating `permission_types` in the `render` method, better in `mount` if it is not highly dynamic (likely to change from render to render).

Populating `permission_resource` in `mount` might look like this:

```
    public function mount() {
        $this->permission_types = PermissionType::all();
        $this->permission_resource = $this->permission_types->pluck('name');
    }
```

Then in the blade, bind to elements of the array, and don't set `checked` yourself, `wire:model` will always override this anyway, checking your checkbox if the thing you have bound to is truthy, and unchecking if bound var is falsey (this is why everything is unchecked for you with the `wire:model` binding them to the array, because `empty($array) == false`, if you just fix the casing of permission_type in the blade you will find the checkbox all come on when you check one, because they are all bound to the same thing).

```
<input wire:model="permission_resource.{{$loop->index}}" type="checkbox" class="filled-in chk-col-green form-control" id="{{$permission_type['name']}}" value="{{$permission_type['name']}}" />
```

PS: That will at least get to what you wanted, depending on what you are ultimately trying to do with permission_resource, it may not be a very good/useful representation for the purpose.

Comment: The checkboxes are preselected, but as soon as i click on any checkbox to uncheck it, it automatically gets checked, so i put wire:mode.defer, but the array seems to remove the items from array and replace it with false.

Comment: This actually solved the problem, all i had to do is to check for false value while running a loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public $permission = [];

protected $rules = [
    ...
    'permission' => 'required|array',
];


public function create()
{


    if ($this->validate()) {
        $data = [
                'name' => $this->name,
                ....
        ];
        $model = Model::create($data);

        if (!empty($this->permission)) {
            $permissionId = PermissionType::whereIn('id', $this->permission)->pluck('id');
            $model->permission()->attach($permissionId); // add name relation instead 'permission' , of create 'attach' of update 'sync'
        }

    }

}


public function render()
{

    return view('livewire.permissions.create-permission-component', [
        'permissions' => PermissionType::select('id', 'name')->get()
    ])
        ->extends('layouts.app')
        ->section('content');
}
```

in View

```
<div class="row">
   @foreach($permissions as $permission)
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <input wire:model.defer="permission" wire:key="permission{{$permission->id}}" type="checkbox" value="{{$permission->id}}" class="filled-in chk-col-green form-control" />
         <label for="{{ $permission->name }}" class="p-r-30">{{ ucfirst($permission->name) }} Resource</label>
      </div>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: I dont know why but your solution is not working at all. none of the checkboxes is preselected.